# Update glimpse tab plugin data using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, glimpse

I'm trying to create a custom glimpse plugin that shows us some information from our server.

When I open the page I get all the data I need but I want to be able to update this data once every 20 seconds(or when i click on a button in the tab) without having to refresh the entire page.

I've managed to add my JavaScript to the page and subscribe to the `render` and `shown` events, but i don't know how to update the tab content when something happens.

This is my tab

```
    public class EagleTab : AspNetTab
    {
        private readonly IGlimpseInterventionService _glimpseInterventionService;
        public EagleTab()
            :this(new GlimpseInterventionService()){}

        public EagleTab(IGlimpseInterventionService glimpseInterventionService)
        {
            _glimpseInterventionService = glimpseInterventionService;
        }
        public override object GetData(ITabContext context)
        {
            var interventionSection = new TabSection("Last modification", "Last Message","Time since last modification","CSE","DPS", "Start Date","End date");
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            var twoHoursThresshold = new TimeSpan(1,0,0);
            foreach(var inv in _glimpseInterventionService.GetActiveInterventions()){
                var timeSinceLastMod = now - inv.LastModification;
                    interventionSection.AddRow()
                        .Column(inv.LastModification)
                        .Column(inv.LastMessage)
                        .Column(timeSinceLastMod.ToString("c"))
                        .Column(inv.CSEName)
                        .Column(inv.DPSName)
                        .Column(inv.StartDate)
                        .Column(inv.EndDate).WarnIf(timeSinceLastMod<twoHoursThresshold);
            }
            var plugin = Plugin.Create("Section", "Data");
            plugin.AddRow().Column("Active interventions").Column(interventionSection);
            return plugin;
        }
        public override string Name
        {
            get { return "Eagle Tab"; }
        }
    }
```

And this is the JavaScript

```
    (function ($, pubsub, tab, render) {
        'use strict';
        function refreshTabContent(){
            //what am I supposed to do here
        }
        pubsub.subscribe('action.panel.rendering.eagle_glimpse_plugins_eagletab', function (args) {

        });
        pubsub.subscribe('action.panel.showed.eagle_glimpse_plugins_eagletab', function (args) {
            setTimeout(refreshTabContent,30000);
        });

    })(jQueryGlimpse, glimpse.pubsub, glimpse.tab, glimpse.render);
```

As you can see in the js there is a function called `refreshTab` i want there to update the content of the tab.

I know that i could make an Ajax call to a controller of mine get the data and then try updating the panel using jQuery but that just seams a bit wrong and i'm hoping there's a better way.

Any tutorial or documentation about glimpse client side extensibility would be welcomed as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have gotten a fairly large amount of the way towards your goal. Unfortunately though there isn't really a way of getting data from a tab outside of a request. That said, there is a "Glimpse" way of getting data from the server. This is small semantic difference, but it has to do with server data, vs request data.

If I was you, I would probably write this as a client side only tab and not implement AspNetTab. [Here](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse.Client/blob/master/test/Plugins.html) are some examples of how this can be done. Next I would implement a Resource. Unfortunately its not very well documented but fortunately its not very hard to work with.

[This](https://github.com/avanderhoorn/Glimpse.Sample.Extensions) repo has some examples of how to work with client tabs back to resources. Specifically the Inventory tab is a tab that lets people mouse over products in the site and have the tab show stock levels. Here is the [resource](https://github.com/avanderhoorn/Glimpse.Sample.Extensions/blob/master/Framework/InventoryResource.cs) and here is the [client code](https://github.com/avanderhoorn/Glimpse.Sample.Extensions/blob/master/Framework/InventoryScript.js) that interacts with the resource (given what you have so far, this should be fairly easy to adapt. Lastly, as a bonus, if you haven't seen it already, here is how to [include](https://github.com/avanderhoorn/Glimpse.Sample.Extensions/blob/master/Framework/InventoryClientScript.cs) your script into your page. Note, the commits on that repo are the step by step guid to how things come together.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Sorry for the huge delay, haven't been able to work on that for a while, already went the `IResource` path, the `renderEngine.insert` was the last part i was missing, thank you